# async & await - How to wait until all Tasks are done?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

ok.  I made a simple console app to figure out how to make all this work. Once I have the basic outline working, then I'll apply it to the real application.

The idea is that we have a lot of database calls to execute that we know are going to take a long time.  We do NOT want to (or have to) wait for one database call to be completed before we make the next. They can all run at the same time.

But, before making all of the calls, we need to perform a "starting" task. And when all of the calls are complete, we need to perform a "finished" task.

Here's where I'm at now:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("starting");
    PrintAsync().Wait();        
    Console.WriteLine("ending");  // Must not fire until all tasks are finished
    Console.Read();
}

// Missing an "await", I know. But what do I await for?
static async Task PrintAsync()
{
    Task.Run(() => PrintOne());
    Task.Run(() => PrintTwo());
}

static void PrintOne()
{
    Console.WriteLine("one - start");
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    Console.WriteLine("one - finish");
}

static void PrintTwo()
{
    Console.WriteLine("two - start");
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    Console.WriteLine("two - finish");
}
```

But no matter what I try, `Ending` always gets printed too early:

```
starting
ending
one - start
two - start
one - finish
two - finish
```

What IS working right is that `PrintTwo()` starts before `PrintOne()` is done.  But how do I properly wait for `PrintAsync()` to finish before doing anything else?

Comment: `Task.Run` returns a `Task`. Await the tasks.

Comment: If you're dealing with DB calls then you should use async methods for talking to the DB because that's IO bound instead of wrapping those calls in `Task.Run`.

Comment: @juharr... ok. So then how do I make it so that I'm not waiting on one DB call to finish before the next starts?

Comment: @CaseyCrookston In the exact same way.  You'd have some `async` methods that do each DB call and you'd capture their tasks and put them in a `Task.WhenAll`.  Basically `PrintOne` and `PrintTwo` would be `async` methods that return `Task` and you wouldn't need to wrap them in `Task.Run`.  You can do that with `await Task.Delay` insteast of `Thread.Sleep`.

Comment: ok, but if I use `await` on each call, then won't they execute one at a time instead of all at the same time?  I'm not seeing this in my head.

Comment: he tells you about using async access methods to the DB and make `async Task PrintOne()` and `async Task PrintTwo()` methods

Comment: You don't do `await` on the `PrintOne` and `PrintTwo` calls, you do `await Task.WhenAll(PrintOne, PrintTwo);`.

Comment: Ah! ok! That makes sense.

Comment: @juharr, see the answer I posted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need to await the ending of the inner tasks:

```
static async Task PrintAsync()
{
    await Task.WhenAll(Task.Run(() => PrintOne()), Task.Run(() => PrintTwo()));
}
```

explanation: `async Task` denotes an awaitable method. Inside this method you can also `await` Tasks. If you don't do this then it will simply let the tasks loose which will run on their own. `Task.Run` returns a `Task` which can be awaited. If you want both tasks to run in parallel you can use the tasks from the retur values and use them in the awaitable method [Task.WhenAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_WhenAll_System_Threading_Tasks_Task___)

EDIT: Actually Visual Studio would mark this code with a green curvy line. When hoovering with the mouse over it you get a warning:

[image]

[CS4014](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs4014)

This should explain why `"ending"` is printed before the tasks have finished

EDIT 2:

If you have a collection of parameters that you want to iterate and call an async method to pass the parameter in, you can also do it with a select statement in 1 line:

```
static async Task DatabaseCallsAsync()
{
    // List of input parameters
    List<int> inputParameters = new List<int> {1,2,3,4,5};  
    await Task.WhenAll(inputParameters.Select(x => DatabaseCallAsync($"Task {x}")));
}

static async Task DatabaseCallAsync(string taskName)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{taskName}: start");
    await Task.Delay(3000);
    Console.WriteLine($"{taskName}: finish");
}
```

The last part is similar to a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57458622/5174469)

Comment: Wooh! Nice! I did not know about Task.WhenAll(). Thank you. I will mark as the answer as soon as it lets me.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston you're welcome. I added an explanation with a link to the documentation. Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you.  Next I need to figure out how to convert the static PrintOne() and PrintTwo() into a loop that still behaves the same way.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston tell me more. Where is the loop supposed to reside?

Comment: :) I'll make a new post if I can't figure it out, and add the link here.

Comment: The link you provided gave me the answer.

Answer (score 0):

OP here. I'm going to leave the answer by Mong Zhu marked as correct, as it lead me to the solution.  But I also want to share the final result here, which includes excellent feedback in the comments from juharr. Here's what I came up with:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("starting");
        DatabaseCallsAsync().Wait();            
        Console.WriteLine("ending"); // Must not fire until all database calls are complete.
        Console.Read();
    }

    static async Task DatabaseCallsAsync()
    {
        // This is one way to do it...
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            tasks.Add(DatabaseCallAsync($"Task {i}"));
        }
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());

        // This is another.  Same result...
        List<int> inputParameters = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        await Task.WhenAll(inputParameters.Select(x => DatabaseCallAsync($"Task {x}")));
    }

    static async Task DatabaseCallAsync(string taskName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{taskName}: start");
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        Console.WriteLine($"{taskName}: finish");
    }
}
```

Here's the result:

```
starting
Task 0: start
Task 1: start
Task 2: start
Task 2: finish
Task 0: finish
Task 1: finish
ending
```

Comment: If you have a colelction of parameters for you async method you can use a simple select statement to execute the async methods and await them (even in a single line) Have a look at my second edit.

Comment: @MongZhu, thanks! That's helpful.  Question: Assuming a huge List<BigObject> instead of a small List<int>, is there a speed advantage to one way vs the other?